# DevExpress DragDrop in treelist throws HRESULT 800ac472

Tags: c#, excel, devexpress, xtratreelist

I observed that, when I drag and drop from parent node to its child node(which technically should not be allowed in a treeview), throws HRESULT 800ac472 exception. It won't even go to AfterDragDrop event handler where I am setting my db values in table. Any solution ?

Comment: Hi, please post the callstack and error message here.  Also, please specify the TreeList's version.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
No Source available, no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code can not be displayed. Version 10.1.5.0

Comment: Does this exception is thrown when you drop one node onto another?  What data is stored in IDataObject?  Do you see the same exception when you throw a node onto, for example, Panel?

Comment: Dragdrop works fine for other nodes. When a node is a parent of some nodes, and u drop that node on one of its child, or drag and drop node on itself, results in crash.

Comment: If so, you can easily resolve this problem by using the DragOver event to prevent a node from being dropped in this case.  Generally, this drop operation is strange as I do not know how the TreeList should behave in this case.

Comment: It shuld simply not allow to drop in such cases. However I will try to implement DragOver event. thanks.